# how to stop a .md file from being generating an html file in jekyll

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

i'm kinda new to jekyll. in my project i have few .md files(each file relate to a portfolio project). some of those need to generate separate .html files when built(which jekyll already does). but i want to exclude some files from being creating separate html files.

But the important thing is, even though i want to exclude those .md files from creating seperate .html files i still want to use the front matter of those files.(as i'm using a for loop to generate a list of all the portfolio projects)

i tryied adding those .md files to the `_config.yml` under `exclude`. but that will stop parsing the front matter as well.

is there a way in jekyll which i can achieve this.

**edit:**

project1.md

```
---
title: project1
display: true
category: portfolioProjects
---

This is a test content
```

project2.md

```
---
title: project2
display: false
category: portfolioProjects
---
```

if i have 2 files like above, i would like to render project1.md as a .html file(as it has a content to be shown in a page) and not generate project2.md as a separate file.But i still want to access front matters of both files to make a list of projects like,

```
{% for project in site.projects %}
{{project.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

> I believe i can use 2 types of collections and set `output` to `true`
>   for one type of collection and `false` to other type of collection.
>   But I'm wondering whether there is a much cleaner way like conditionally setting `output` to `true` or `false` depending on a front matter value.
>   eg. `output : (display)? true : false`

Comment: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/

Comment: @DavidJacquel thanks for the link, but i still coudn't figure out a way to access front meta from _config.yml. i can use a new collection and use the output property to make those type of collection files to generate a .html file or not. But i want to conditionally set output to `true || false` depending on a front matter attribute inside the collection files. is this possible in jekyll

Comment: No way with raw jekyll. You will need to write a plugin.

Comment: Can't you just add an additional no_display category to the respective files and exclude all posts matching this category when looping through all your posts?

Comment: what did you end up doing. I tried 2 collections, one with output true, other false. they are both generating for me.